# Booting to black screen (possible ecryptfs failure)

Tags: boot, ecryptfs

I've been running 20.10 on my machine without problems for a while now. I was in the process of trying to encrypt the home folder of a second user with `ecryptfs` following this article
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/how-to-encrypt-home-folder-in-ubuntu.html
But I ran into an error that some files were still in use by that user even though the user was logged out. I still had not rebooted the computer.

I then moved onto some to some other tasks, and in the process of doing something else, I rebooted the computer.

Maybe all the above is unrelated, but right now when I try to boot up I only get to a black screen.

I have the option to getting to the grub bootloader before the black screen, but I'm not sure what my problem even is, let alone how to solve it :(

---

UPDATE: I've been trying to boot into text only mode from the grub menu without success (as in it still just loads a black screen)

And an attempt at booting into Recovery mode hangs after "Loading initial ramdisk..."

Comment: for the record, I didn't find a solution. @matigo suggestion gave me a lot of options to try different techniques, but none solved the problem of the black screen. In the end I backed up the data while in liveboot, and reinstalled Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting a home folder should not affect the boot process, but I am curious about what some of the "other tasks" were. Did you update any of the software on the system?

If you have a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu on it, [give these steps a try](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure). This will update your installed software and, if there are issues, hopefully resolve them.

Comment: > _what some of the "other tasks" were_ < 
well, it was two days of working, so can't be sure really. I do think there was a software update that failed to complete due to the wifi dropping.

----
I created a boot disk, mounted the root partition, and ran through those steps to update, but after umount and reboot, still a black screen.